# make array of angles with linspace function in python

Tags: python, numpy

> We want to know the sine values from 0 to 2π but just multiples of π/2 . You can use both np.arange() and np.linspace(). But we ask you to use np.linspace(). Then use np.sin(). You should know that a mathematical function like sin whose argument is a array, will operate on whole elements of array.
> First create an array using np.linspace() according to above description and call it C. Then use np.sin() on array C.

**my teacher want to make array of angles that are multiples of pi/2 with linspase() but i don`t know how to do!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import math
import numpy as np
C = np.linspace(0,2*math.pi)*math.pi/2
C = np.sin(C)
print(C)
```